# display huge Images in Android

Tags: android, image, memory, view, png

I'm intending to display very large Images in Android. 
**My first solution** - to supply them as pdf - fails because not every handheld got a pdf-viewer preinstalled, and I don't want to require the users to install one.

So I have a png now **(width = 3998px height=2827px)** that I want to display. I downloaded this image to test how it would be displayed the gallery. It was quite painful. It seems that the galery renders this picture only once, and if I Zoom in, I cannot read the text at all.
So I wrote a testActivity which simply has an ImageView nested in a LinearLayout. I put the image into the drawable and set it as ImageView's image-source.
Unforunately the app crashes immediatly, due to an "

```
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8906): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget"
```

I didn't expect that ONE single Image can be too large for`VM's memory`. I played a little bit around, set `ImageViews` size to `3998 & 2827px` , put the Image to `sdCard` and read it manually with a `fileInputStream`.
To my big surprise it now shows my image, but if I turn my **Nexus S horizontal** I get the same `OutOfMemoryError` as before.
Can somewone point me the main difference between recieving a Bitmap through a `FileInputStream` or to set it as `ImageView's` source.   
Also I'm not able to scroll comfortable with two parent `scrollViews`
I searching for a simple solution to display `ONE large image` at a time with the ability to `scroll horizontal and vertical` while able to zoom in and out.

here is a sample of the image I want to display
[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I know it's an old post but I spent a lot of time on this problem, so here's my solution.

I wanted to display a 2000×3000 picture but I got out of memory or the image was too large to be displayed.

To begin, I get the dimensions of the picture:

```
o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
pictures = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
```

Then I cut it up into four parts and displayed them with four ImageViews.
I tried to load the full picture and cut it into four (using `BitmapFactory.create(bitmap,int,int,int,int)`) but got out of memory again.

So I decided to use some BitMapRegionDecoder:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);         
        InputStream istream =   null;
        try {
         istream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
         e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BitmapRegionDecoder decoder     =   null;
        try {
        decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(istream, false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
    int nw = (j*width/k);
    int nh = (i*height/k);

    Bitmap bMap = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(nw,nh, (nw+width/k),(nh+height/k)), null);    
    iv.setImageBitmap(bMap);

    }
}
```

This worked.

Comment: Nice Solution. I now found an even better way (with much coding effort) by tiling my Images. I also have 3 Versions of the same picture in different qualitys for different ZoomLevels. This will work even on old devices, which are failing to decode 1/4 of the original Bitmap

Comment: What is **k** in here? Hope **width** and **height** means the actual image dimensions. Please clarify that.

Comment: Rafael: You shouldn't (in theory!) need different resolution versions - check out `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize`.

Comment: @leadersheep : can you tell us what's the value of *k* here?

Comment: Here, I cut my picture in 4 parts, so the k = 2

Comment: What if i am having a 30x30 image and i want to display it as 150x150?

Answer (score 7):

I know its an old question but I used TileView to do exactly this:

https://github.com/moagrius/TileView

Answer (score 7):

Try to use this one:
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

> A custom image view for Android, designed for photo galleries and
>   displaying huge images (e.g. maps and building plans) without
>   OutOfMemoryErrors. Includes pinch to zoom, panning, rotation and
>   animation support, and allows easy extension so you can add your own
>   overlays and touch event detection.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: But this library couldn't rotate the image using touches, it allow to rotate 90 degrees only.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this "easy to integerate" source of WorldMap application:

https://github.com/johnnylambada/WorldMap

This uses a huge image of a world map, and uses cache to display a map.

To integerate, I just copied all the java files (5 i guess) and used the surfaceView in my layout file. Then I went through the small OnCreate() method of ImageViewerActivity.java and used the code in my activity (with sligh alteration, depending on my personal use).

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=content;siu-container) is a good demo for zooming a picture using multi touch gestures. It uses Matrix to zoom as well as pan a picture.

Answer (score 1):

To handle scaling etc and using full resolution, You can use MapView of OSM (open street map) and provide it with your tiles (instead of the map). Check this: http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30

Answer (score 1):

We have to follow following steps to remove out of memory exception while loading huge images:

```
 1. Read Bitmap Dimensions and Type

 2. Load a Scaled down version into memory
```

Android Developer's Guide defines how we achieve these.
here is the link

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap