# Handling Large Bitmaps in Image Editor

Tags: android, bitmap

For the program I am currently writing I need a simple image editor. Essentially the user navigates to this editor by simply selecting an image from a gallery. Upon selection the image editor activity is created and should allow the user to perform simple editing actions such as rotation, brightness adjustment, zoom etc.

At the moment I have managed to implement the aforementioned functionality with relative ease. My problem lies in dynamically adding the image in question to the `ImageView`. As many of you might know; the Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process. Thus I am only able to load compressed versions of the bitmap into my ImageView and this presents a rather large problem for me (my program is mainly designed for use on tablets). I have done significant research on this issue and have found that one can essentially split a Bitmap into several smaller bitmaps and place them in several ImageView to create the illusion of one contiguous image using `BitmapRegionDecoder`(as suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518215/display-huge-images-in-android)). While this has successfully allowed me to display large images I have no idea how I am supposed to implement zooming functionality using multiple instances of `ImageView`. Is there a relatively simple way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [video from Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbQb1PVjfqM&list=PL46069800A957F535&index=10) where they develop an Advanced gallery app with image editing.

You can download source code for the application [here](http://code.google.com/p/iogallery/). This is how it opens the activity for image editing:

```
private OnItemClickListener mPhotoClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // User clicked on photo, open our viewer
        final Intent intent = new Intent(AlbumActivity.this, PhotoActivity.class);
        final Uri data = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);
        intent.setData(data);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

The gallery also implements image editing functionality. The code might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this? options.inJustDecodeBounds should be set to true.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html