# How to display big image in Android

Tags: android, imageview

I see in this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appvl.haivl
Sometimes it shows a big image with height larger than 2048px, such as: http://s4.haivl.com/data/photos2/20130623/ce07dcc8255b49b4a55a9cd265db9872/medium-571180dcb6e34226960556476e87483c-400.jpg (exactly 400x2645px, but its size is small - 211KB).

But when I make a demo to show this image, I always get "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture" exception.

I'm sure there is way to show this image, because in the above app, it's possible.

Can anyone suggest how can I display such image without need to scale down it?

I'll appreciate much.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518215/display-huge-images-in-android    http://zerocredibility.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/android-bitmap-scaling/

Comment: Hi @MichaelShrestha : thanks for your link. I'm reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @MichaelShrestha for his link. Finally I found a way to display big image in Android by using BitmapRegionDecoder. Check this link for the sample code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12161993/190309

Comment: You asked for a solution where you don't scale the image down. And accepted an answer which does exactly that.

Comment: @MichałK He is like, "My question, my answer, my rules"

Answer (score 4):

Turn off Hardware Acceleration.

Either on the Activity from the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity ... />
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

Or on the View displaying the image:

```
yourView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```