# ImageView image is not appearing on large screen mobiles

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

i am having a image of large height around 2000dp. i wanna display it in ImageView , that can scroll up to its height. i wrote the following xml file , it works fine on devices but not on HTC one X , Samsung galaxy S4 , etc i thing its the issue with large screen mobile devices , can anyone help me out . i will be highly thankful to him/her.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2000dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/total"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2000dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/upperRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/dayview_bg" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try to [downsize your image](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to 1) match the device screen size and 2) to avoid memory issues, 2000dp is above the regular dimensions of existing standard devices.

You could follow the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to define the different layouts depending on targeted devices :

> - res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
> - res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
> - res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
> - res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
> - res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
>
> **Configuration examples**
>
> To help you target some of your designs for different types of devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:
>
> - 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
> - 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
> - 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
> - 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

If you don't want to downsize the entire image, the [BitmapRegionDecoder class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) could help you (a case of use can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12161993))

Comment: i have a large image , thats why i used a scrollview to scroll it up and down , why u r telling about supporting multiple screens , thats not what i ask .

Comment: Due to limited memory on most devices, your image cannot stay on memory (out of memory issue); you could try to shrink it, display part of its in your layout, use a webview that has a built-in zoom feature (load image using <img src="image_path"> in an HTML page)

Comment: The [BitmapRegionDecoder class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) could help you (a case of use can be found in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12161993))