# Same as gallery app how to show large bitmap image above 2048 android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

While try to load large bitmap image above 2048 its showing error :

03-20 12:20:56.515: W/OpenGLRenderer(17398): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture.

So I displayed image after scaled down to 2048 but I lost actual size. when I check android gallery, same image is displayed properly  with scrolling option. Can any one give a  suggestion to load image effectively.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518215/display-huge-images-in-android) link, should help you to get the job done

Comment: Thank you for this link.Nice Solution. I now found an even better way.