# out of memory issue bitmap when i load two image from gallary in one activity

Tags: android, bitmap

I am developing an app of photoframes. user can select two image from gallary in one frame. but whenever i set any one image from gallary and then going to select other image application crash and in log shows an error message out of memory.
how i remove this error

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();


                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String


                imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));


            }
            if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();


                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
               // 
                imageView2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            }
  }
```

please help me

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518215/display-huge-images-in-android

Comment: Use [Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Volley Library](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) for Loading Image. It will keep your application smooth and free from out of memory issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try below code hope it will help you

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File file, int width, int height)
    {
        try
        {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o);
            int scale = 1;

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = width;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = height;



            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o2);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please use [Android-Collage-View library](https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views) . it meets your requirement which you want

Comment: this Works fine . but i have one issue i am also implementing on touch listener on imageviw. so rotate is not working in this condition

Comment: Please see this url :-> https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views . it meets your requirement which you want